# Can create a table but doesn't display in Object explorer, can't select, or delete table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Using SQL Server 2016.  Have a locally hosted database that uses the Windows login for the sa, which is what I am using to login.

Yesterday I ran

```
CREATE TABLE [Otis].[AnalyzerGroups] 
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL
);
```

and got command successfully completed. Today I tried selected from this table but got an error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Invalid object name 'Otis.AnalyzerGroups'

So I thought I misremembered and tried running the create statement again but then got the error -

> Msg 15530, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> The object with name "AnalyzerGroups" already exists.
> The statement has been terminated.

So then I tried `DROP TABLE [Otis].[AnalyzerGroups];` and got

> Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 1
> Cannot drop the table 'Otis.AnalyzerGroups', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

I tried making a new test table and the same thing. The first time I run the create statement command successfully completes, but then I can't select / insert / drop from the table, and I cannot see it in the Object explorer either.

I assume this must be some permissions issue but I don't know what property is keeping me from viewing these tables - its not like I'm putting security on these tables, and I can see every other table in our database. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you changing database context, is it a different query window?

Comment: I right click on the database I am using and click "New Query" in my object editor.  There are 3 other databases other than the one I am using, however I checked all of them and also do not see the table I created in any of them.

Comment: At the top left you can select which database to use. The object explorer does not update after `CREATE TABLE` unless you right click and press refresh

Answer (score 0):

You put it most likely in the wrong database.  Try this.

```
sp_MSforeachdb 'SELECT "?" AS DB, * FROM [?].sys.tables WHERE name like 
''%AnalyzerGroups%'''
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a trigger in the SQL Server database that fired any time a new table was created under any schema, and would then transfer it to the `dbo` schema.  So my tables did exist, but they were under the schema I was expecting because of this trigger.  Why does this trigger exist?  Got me.  But it's in production and has been for over a decade so there's some reason/it's definitely not changing.  Thanks for the help though everyone.